# Code Review Checklist

Tags: asp.net

Please provide me some parameters to evaluate the code effeciency till now I included the following in my code checklist:

1. Warnings are in the Code (No/Yes)
2. Code Analysis by Tool Report
3. Unused Using
4. Unit Test Cases
5. Indentation
6. Null Reference Exception
7. Naming Convention
8. Code Reusability
9. Code Consistency
10. Comments
11. Code Readability
12. Use of Generics
13. Speed
14. Disposing of Unmanaged Resources
15. Exception Handling
16. Length of Code (Number of Lines) 30-40 lines per method
17. Is Nested For/ Foreach loop is used?
18. Use of Linq or Lambda
19. Usage of access specifiers (private, public, protected, internal, protected internal) as per the scope
20. Usage of  interfaces wherever needed to maintain decoupling
21. Marking of a class as sealed or static or abstract as per its usage and your need.
22. Use a Stringbuilder instead of string if multiple concatenations required, saving heap memory.
23. Any unreachable code exists and if possible modifies the code if it exists.

Comment: This question belongs to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I would start by defining "software efficiency". This article gives a hint: https://www.keenesystems.com/blog/defining-efficiency-as-a-software-requirement

According to ISO 25010: efficiency is "resources expended in relation to the accuracy and completeness with which users achieve goals"

Then, it could be "Performance efficiency" with meaning "performance relative to the amount of resources used under stated conditions" and criteria such as

- Time behavior
- Resource utilization
- Capacity

Other norms include ISO/IEC 9126-1, ISO/IEC 25062 and ISO 9241-11

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9241#ISO_9241-11

"System Efficiency: For evaluating system efficiency, the researcher records the time (in seconds) that participants took to complete each task."

Also interesting: [which code is consuming less power?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011260/which-code-is-consuming-less-power/11011750#11011750)

**Finally**: "Productivity (also referred to as efficiency) is the amount of
product produced for an amount of resource. For software, productivity is commonly measured by size (ESLOC) divided by effort hours." see [Department of Defense Software Factbook](https://resources.sei.cmu.edu/asset_files/TechnicalReport/2017_005_001_502661.pdf)

To sum this up. I think you should update your list and focus on what you really want and need to measure, and what is generic about the system or software and what is e.g. language specific efficiency criteria.